# Change background of particular item to a colour and other items to different colour

Tags: android

[image: Display]

I am passing the list to dialog. In that if I select one item, the background should change to green. And again if I select another item that item background should change to green and the previously selected item background should assign to default.

For example: if I select "Chart 3", background should change to green. And if I select "Chart 5", the background of "Chart 5" should change to green and "Chart 3" background should change to default.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
public ConfigureDialogAdapter(Context context, List<PhrToolBar> listData) {
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  mToolBarList = listData;
}

public void setDialogClickListener(DialogClickListener dialogClickListener) {
  mDialogClickListener = dialogClickListener;
}

public void setToolBarList(List<PhrToolBar> list) {
  mToolBarList = list;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

  View rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_dialog_list_adapter, parent, false);
  return new ViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

  PhrToolBar current = mToolBarList.get(position);
  viewHolder.textView.setText(current.getTitle());

  if (current.isVisible()){
     viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
  } else {
     viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
  }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  CheckBox checkBox;
  TextView textView;

  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setOnClickListener(onTextClick);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckBoxClick);
  }

  View.OnClickListener onTextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);

      if (mDialogClickListener != null) {
         mDialogClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }
  };

  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckBoxClick = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

      if (mDialogClickListener != null) {
        if (isChecked) {
           mDialogClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(true, getAdapterPosition());
        } else {
           mDialogClickListener.onCheckBoxClick(false, getAdapterPosition());
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
  return mToolBarList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a selector drawable like this one (in res/drawable folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_selected="true">
   <shape>
         <solid android:color="@color/green" />
   </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_selected="false">
    <shape>
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then, in your raw layout just add the background layout and mark the raw as clickable :

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:clickable="true"
```

Also, add setSelected to your `OnClickListener` :

```
View.OnClickListener onTextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textView.setSelected(true);

      if (mDialogClickListener != null) {
         mDialogClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }
  };
```

Everytime you mark your item as `setSelected(true)`, it will be green !
Also, you should keep the selection state in an arrayand change your code to something like this :

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 //Add this, this array will store selected items
 SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

 [...]
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

  PhrToolBar current = mToolBarList.get(position);
  viewHolder.textView.setText(current.getTitle());

  //add this, If the item position is in the array, it will be marked as selected (so green), otherwise background will be default one (transparent)
  viewHolder.textView.setSelected(selectedItems.get(position, false));

  if (current.isVisible()){
     viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
  } else {
     viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
  }
}
[...]

View.OnClickListener onTextClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      //Add this to add the position to the array storing selected item !       
      if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
         selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
      } else {
         selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
      }  
 notifyDataSetChanged ();

      textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

      if (mDialogClickListener != null) {
         mDialogClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: When i click on item, background turns to green. If i remove my finger, background turns to white.

Comment: this works. But when i click on other item, the previously selected item background remains green. My requirement is that the previously selected item background should turn to white.

Comment: edited, you need to keep track of selected/unselected item !

Comment: This is not working bro. The previously selected item's background doesn't change.

Comment: use notifyd1tasetchanged after the click event

Comment: Still no change

Comment: "Every time you mark your item as isSelected(true), il will be green !."  where should i use isSelected?

Comment: I meant setSelected